# Converting print data from MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table in the database MS Access, which contains a large number of columns. I need to print the data on a standard A4 sheet in landscape format. In the records of the table data that can be transferred to the next line, because the same data type (see the example in the picture). The most important thing is that all the data fits onto one sheet of A4 in landscape format for print. What is the easiest way to do this? Transfer to Excel? Or create a form in MS Access? VBA

[image]

Comment: Some sort of crosstab query then report, I imagine...

Comment: Just make a report and you can format it however you want. Use the report wizard, then drag and drop things around as necessary -  make fonts smaller, stack fields, etc